# How to select the new element just added dynamically in a select directive

Tags: angularjs, select, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I am building a directive with a select list in order to add dynamically elements.

The following doesn't work : I'm adding an element to the array model used in the ng-model-options binding of my directive. 
The element is nicely added to the list **but it's not being selected**. Instead I keep getting the empty line. I can't find a way to set the ng-model to the newly added element.

I have tried a scope.$watch on my item list inside the directive but strangely nothing is fired when the item list is increased by one new element. And I don't understand why : if the list is being updated so should scope.items, which should trigger the scope.$watch...

```
scope.$watch('items', function(){
      scope.ngModel = scope.items[0];
});
```

I have made a plunker to illustrate this : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rTs08DZU8fzi2S4REvwn?p=preview)

Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: are you adding items from within angular scope? If using code outside of angukar will need `$apply()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope))

```
scope.$watch('items', function(){
      scope.ngModel = scope.items[0];
}, true);  // Add third parameter true, this will make sure you check if the list 
           // has changed and not only if a new list was added

// Without the third parameter: 
var list = [];
list.push('test'); // won't call watch

var list = ['test'];
list = ['new array']; //will call watch
```

Comment: Awesome. Not sure where you found that in the documentation.. but thumbs up for the trick!

Comment: And there it is : $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]); When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is determined according to the angular.equals function.